# Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child. How do i interpret the error message and find the error?

Tags: react-native

for some reason my code wont run anymore and im unable to track down the error.

Error is presented in the debugger like this:

```
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in LoginScreen (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
    in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:61)
    in Navigator (at createAppContainer.js:429)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:19)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at View.js:35)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:35)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

This error is located at:
    in LoginScreen (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
    in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:61)
    in Navigator (at createAppContainer.js:429)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:19)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at View.js:35)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:35)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

As I understand it, its saying im trying to display an object. But i dont think that I am.
Here is my code, first app.js where the navigation is configured.

```
//imports are omitted
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}

const CallLogStackNav = createStackNavigator({
  Telefonlogg: {
    screen: CallHistoryScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        headerTitle: 'Telefonlogg',
        headerLeft: (
          <Icon
            style={{paddingLeft: 10}}
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            name="menu"
          />
        ),
      };
    },
  },
  Billing: {
    screen: BillingScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        headerTitle: 'Time registrering',
      };
    },
  },
});

const SettingsStackNav = createStackNavigator({
  Instillinger: {
    screen: SettingsScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        headerLeft: (
          <Icon
            style={{paddingLeft: 10}}
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            name="menu"
          />
        ),
        headerTitle: 'Instillinger',
      };
    },
  },
  Svarteliste: {
    screen: BlacklistScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        headerTitle: 'Svarteliste',
      };
    },
  },
});

const AppDrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator({
  Hjem: {screen: CallLogStackNav},
  Instillinger: {screen: SettingsStackNav},
});
const AppSwitchNav = createSwitchNavigator({
  Login: {screen: LoginScreen},
  Dashboard: {screen: AppDrawerNav},
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNav);
```

And heres the "LoginScreen" that i think is giving me the error (again imports are omitted):

```
class LoginScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const callHistory = await CallHistory.request.fetchCallHistory();
    if (callHistory !== null) {
      this.setState({callLogs: callHistory, isLoading: false});
      await LocalStorage.function.setItem(
        '@callLog.Origin',
        this.state.callLogs,
      );
    }
  }

  async render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <SplashScreen />;
    }
    if ((await Auth.function.getToken()) !== 'err:noToken') {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
    }
    return (
      <Container style={styles.wrapper}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={require('../assets/dlxbgxxxhdpi.png')}
          style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.formContainer}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Brukernavn"
              style={styles.inputs}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({username: text})}
            />
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Passord"
              style={styles.inputs}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({password: text})}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={async () => {
                if (
                  (await Auth.function.login(
                    this.state.username,
                    this.state.password,
                  )) === true
                ) {
                  this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
                } else {
                  this.setState({username: '', password: ''});
                }
              }}>
              <Text style={styles.btText}> Logg Inn </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
export default LoginScreen;
```

I have been trying to figure it out for some time now, and would appriciate it if someone could give me a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lifecycle methods cant have the `async` modifiers.

remove `async` keywords from `render()` and `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Ah okei, that seems to fix it, ran into something else wonky:

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('didmount');
    this.getCallHistory().then(r => console.log(r));
  }

doesent actully run at anytime, or atleast it does not show up in the console.